# Is there a way to easily get only the log entries for a specific AWS Lambda execution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

Lambda obviously tracks executions, since you can see data points in the Lambda Monitoring tab.

Lambda also saves the logs in log groups, however I get the impression that Lambda launches are reused if happening in a shorter interval (say 5 minutes between launches), so the output from multiple executions gets written to the same log stream.

This makes logs a lot harder to follow, especially due to other limitations (the CloudWatch web console is super slow and cumbersome to navigate, `aws log get-log-events` has a 1MB/10k message limitation which makes it cumbersome to use).

Is there some way to only get Lambda log entries for a specific Lambda execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter by the `RequestId`. Most loggers will include this in the log, and it is automatically included in the `START`, `END`, and `REPORT` entries.

Comment: I just tried it, copy pasted the `RequestId` from the logs in the "Filter events" search box, nothing is shown, everything is filtered out.

Comment: Ok, found it, but it's dumb. The `RequestIds` contain dashes by default. The filter patterns treat the dashes as minuses so they break up the `RequestIds` and can't find anything. Have to quote them...

Comment: You probably need to put quotes around it

Comment: Yeah, I noticed... Thanks for the hint! Now I just need to re-enable the AWS root logger which I had just disabled because it was doubling all my log entries :-D

Answer (score 2):

My current approach is to use CloudWatch Logs Insights to query for the specific logs that I'm looking for. Here is the sample query:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @requestId = '5a89df1a-bd71-43dd-b8dd-a2989ab615b1'
| sort @timestamp
| limit 10000
```

Comment: That's really cool, but is this available for Docker-based Lambdas?

Comment: @oblio What's Docker-based Lambda?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html

Comment: @oblio Yeah, of course. It should definitely work for Lambdas deployed using a container image.

Comment: You think? I couldn't find how to enable it for Docker, the docs are for standard Lambda packages, with Lambda layers :-(

Comment: I'm accepting the other answer as it's a bit more straightforward than Insights. However if anyone wants to go this route, for Docker you'll need to package the Insights stuff in your Docker container, see: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/using-extensions.html#invocation-images-extensions 
and 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/get-layer-version-by-arn.html Both answers are valid, though, the other one is just simpler :-)